# Is it possible to get an access to anonymous user identity in ASP.NET Core running in IIS?

Tags: security, iis, asp.net-core, identity, anonymous

With asp.net vPrev we was able to separate application pool account and access account for anonymous access ("anonymous user identity", IUSR be default). This is extremely helpful to secure the app: you may sure that no high level access will be provided for anonymous, even if application pool account has high privileges.

Is it any way to do the same for ASP.NET Core application? From my understanding of core's execution model that will not be possible, because IIS act just as a proxy. Am I right?

May be there are some ways to do the same but with an another approach? The main goal is to have ability to switch context between application pool and anonymous context. As simple example: when app starting we can read\write\do whatever with application pool account, but inside request context we will operate with anonymous user identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fan of answering own questions, but subject is possible. You can get anonymous user context from IIS SDK:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration // from Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll, nuget microsoft.web.administration
// ....
Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", siteName);
string userName = (string)anonymousAuthenticationSection["userName"];
string pwd = (string)anonymousAuthenticationSection["password"];
```

Of course this is not really secure (in have to run your app under account that have access to IIS) and you need to keep site name somewhere in config, but it works.